# Сохранить изменения в listBox. C#. Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Добавляю items в listBox через textBox (listBox1.Items.Add(insertBox.Text)
Как сделать так чтоб после закрытия открытия формы изменения в listBox сохранялись?

Comment: Сохранить `File.WriteAllLines("listbox.txt", listBox1.Items.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())`, загрузить `listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("listbox.txt"))`

Comment: Для хранение данных вне сессии есть много различных способов. Самый простой, как по мне, это Properties.Settings. Также можно хранить настройки в файл, реестре, на сервер и т.д.

Comment: @KuzCode данные, вводимые прользователем, хранить в реестре нельзя. Иначе пользователь вставит в `insertBox` 500 мегабайт текста, и начнется веселье.

Comment: @aepot во втором предложении я уже говорил про сохранение настроек в общем, реестр обычно нужен для коротких штук типу пути каталога, флагов и т.д.

Comment: @aepot  Ваш метод отлично сработал спасибо.